# PytestBDD target_fixture - PytestDeprecationWarning

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-bdd

When I run `pytest` on the following code:

```
import requests

from pytest_bdd import scenario, given, when, then

@scenario('../features/user.feature', 'Create a new user')
def test_create_user():
    pass

@given('a valid user payload')
def valid_user_payload():
    return {
        "username": "TEST"
    }

@when('a client calls POST /users', target_fixture='response')
def create_user():
    api_base_url = "https://localhost:8080"
    response = requests.post(f"{api_base_url}/users", json="user_payload")
    return response
```

I get this warning: "... .venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytest_bdd/steps.py:211: PytestDeprecationWarning: A private pytest class or function was used.
fd = FixtureDef(
"

When I remove the `target_fixture` parameter from the `@when` decorator, the warning goes away. I understand I can capture the warning but I don't want to capture deprecation warnings, I'd rather know what's causing this and how to fix it.

This is my requirements.txt file:

```
pytest==8.0.0
boto3==1.34.39
pytest-bdd==7.0.1
devtools==0.12.2
requests==2.31.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem.  I suspect the problem is between pytest and pytest-bdd, and not yours or my code.  For now I run tests with:

```
pytest -W ignore::pytest.PytestDeprecationWarning
```

which you can configure by creating (or modifying) **pytest.ini**:

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::pytest.PytestDeprecationWarning
```

ETA: I know your preference is not to suppress warnings (me too!) but it took me a while to learn how to do this, so for those facing the same issue this may be helpful.